# How to determine the order of evaluation of a mathematical expression?

Tags: c#, java, algorithm

Given a mathematical expression, I would like to find out which are the parts that can be evaluated simultaneously. For example, given the following expression,

```
(a + b) * c - (d + e) / f
```

`(a + b)` and `(d + e)` could be evaluated simultaneously because they are independent of each other.

Is there any algorithm for this purpose?
Or is there even any library that implements this functionality?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "independent of each other". Are you saying that they are independent because they don't share any variables in common? It seems like even if a appeared in the second expression as in (a + e) you could still evaluate (a + b) and (a + e) in parallel, no? Because all variables are read-only during the evaluation? You question sounds similar to one that makes more sense to me, which is: how can you make sure you don't evaluate the same sub-expression more than once. For that, see memoization.

Comment: "independent" in the sense that they can be evaluated simultaneously... Normally, if I had to evaluate an expression, I would do it in order, so I first would evaluate `(a + b)`, then I would multiply the result of `(a + b)` by `c`, etc. However you could make parallel evaluations.

Comment: So, right, if your expression is in a tree (see Ido.Co's picture below), you just mean that you don't want to evaluate a parent node at the same time you're evaluating a child node. But that's not something you'd be tempted to do anyway, right? Since you have to evaluate the child node as part of evaluating the parent node anyway.

Comment: After finding the indipendent parts of an expression, each part can be evaluated at the same time on a different host / processor.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. To find the independent parts, make a tree like Ido.Co says, and just don't evaluate a parent at the same time you evaluate one of its children. My point was just that that's not something you'd be tempted to do anyway.

Comment: Do you like find them to improve time complexity or you have other purposes?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I'm implementing an application for distributed computing, and I had to choose the type of processing, so I chose the evaluation of a mathematical expression.

Comment: This is not good choice, because e.g in your accepted answer you should parse input string one time which is O(n) then you can do a bit optimizations like finding independent parts. but they didn't affect the performance.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Sure, but the operations to be performed may also be time consuming operations. Furthermore, the application will also support the addition of new operations via plugin, so it's reasonable to think that certain operations could be quite onerous in terms of time.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri , imagine the case of doing this optimization over an evaluation of expressions containing very very very large numbers...

Comment: @Ido.Co, hoom this makes sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/math-parser-part-1-introduction) is a short and simple step by step manual for creating math parser.
After you have parsed the expression, and you hold a tree representing parsed expression, you can iterate over it, and in every iteration each pairs leaves of the tree will represent an independent expression (that can be evaluated simultaneously). [in every iteration replace the evaluated expressions with their result]

[Building Expression Evaluator with Expression Trees in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335587/Building-Expression-Evaluator-with-Expression-Tree)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation depends on two factor :

- **Precedence** : in each language usually there is a table that indicate the precedence of each operator
- **Associativity** : when an expression involves several operators that have the same precedence, the operator associativity governs the order in which the operations are performed.

*If there could be some optimization that involve simultaneous evaluation of parts of an expression, i think could be done only at **JVM/CLR level** and not with a library ...*

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use the [Reversed Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). 
Read the following for more details:

- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35320-reverse-polish-notation-in-c%23/
- http://www.calculator.org/rpn.aspx

[This is](http://snipplr.com/view/8962/infix-notation-to-reverse-polish-notation/) a function written in C++ that converts normal notation to reversed polish notation. someone might help you in converting it to C#:

Answer (score 1):

Ok so let's see the example as a tree:

```
          -
   (*           /)
(c    +)     (+    f)
   (a   b) (d   e)
```

(brackets pair the nodes that are both children of the same parent)

Getting that tree if simple, for example with the Shunting Yard algorithm.

Now observe that what you need in order to evaluate a node, are only the children of that node (but recursively so). Therefore `(a + b)` and `(d + e)` do not depend on each other, as you note. Also `(c * (a + b))` does not depend on `(d + e)` or on `((d + e) / f)`, and `((d + e) / f)` does not depend on `(a + b)`.

In general, taking a node `n`, any node that's neither a descendant of `n` not a ancestor, can be evaluated simultaneously. If you're working with a schedule, you'd have to add "if that node can be evaluated now" - clearly you can not evaluate a node before you've evaluated its descendants.

I'm not sure what "this purpose" is what you refer to. What do you want to calculate?

Comment: "this purpose": to find the indipendent parts of an expression. Each part can be evaluated at the same time on a different host / processor.